# How to create a file in a folder

Tags: python

How can i create a `.pck` file in a folder in Python?
The name of the folder is example
I tried:

```
file = open("\example\file.pck","wb")
```

But it says:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\example\x0cile.pck'

EDIT:
Solved! The right command is:
`file = open("example/file.pck", "wb")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use forward slashes and also it seems that the `example` folder you trying to access doesn't exist. That's probably because you wanted to enter relative address but you entered an absolute one. So it should be:

`open("example/file.pck", "wb")`

Comment: @MatteoSecco glad to help. Please accept the answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 3):

Use forward slashes

```
open("/example/file.pck", "wb")
```

Your problem is likely that backslashes were being interpreted as [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: Now it says FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/example/file.pck' ... its obvious that it doesn't exist... i want to CREATE it!

Comment: I replaced the slashes as you said, and now my script is exactly the same as yours...and I've also checked if an "example" folder exists in the same folder as the script..and it does.

Comment: OK, it's true that the directory needs to exist already.  If that's still not working, I can not help you any further.

Comment: I've just found the problem. I tried to remove the first slash and now it works ( file = open("example/file.pck", "wb") )

Comment: Yes, `/example` is a generally different directory than `./example`.

Answer (score 0):

Paths can be tricky, especially if you want to run your code on Unix-based and Windows systems. You can avoid many problems by using `os.path` which generates paths that will work on any os.

To open a new file use the 'w+' option instead of 'rw'.

In your case:

```
import os
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.curdir, 'file.pck')
file = open(file_path,'w+')
```